# My Array holds previous values too every time i use.

Tags: javascript

```
var TransactionObject  = {
    arr1: [],
    arr2: []    
};
```

My Array holds previous values too every time i use my model class.

```
var data = update(TransactionObject.arr1);
JsonClient.send(data );
```

The first time the array holds some value, and the next time when i make the request... it adds the previous data too... the array is not getting cleared at all.

Comment: You are going to have to give us more details. It is not clear what you are trying to do ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the data each time before adding new data, then somewhere your code just needs to clear the array.  You could do it like this:

```
TransactionObject.arr1 = [];
var data = update(TransactionObject.arr1);
JsonClient.send(data );
```

Or, you could do it inside your `update()` function like this before putting data into the passed array:

```
var data = update(TransactionObject.arr1);
JsonClient.send(data );

function update(results) {
    results = [];
    // now put data into results
}
```